# Ideal Postgres Index For Json Data With Integer Timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, query-planner

I have millions of records in this table using Amazon Aurora Postgres 10.7:

```
create table "somedb"."sometable"
(
    id varchar(4096) not null constraint "sometable_pkey" primary key,
    tag varchar(255) not null,
    json jsonb not null
);
```

Example row:

`{"id": "abc", "ts": 1580879910, "data": "my stuff"}`

I have these queries that take dozens of seconds:

```
SELECT jsonData->'data'
WHERE (jsonData->>'ts' >= '1576000473')
ORDER BY jsonData->>'ts' ASC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 50000;
```

I'm trying to improve performance here, and these are all the indexes that I tried, but at most I get an INDEX SCAN in the query plan at best.

```
create index "sometable_ts"
on "somedb"."sometable" ((jsondata -> 'ts'::text));

create index "sometable_ts-int" 
on "somedb"."sometable" using btree (((jsondata ->> 'ts')::integer));
```

I adjust my queries as well to: `ORDER BY (jsonData->>'ts')::integer`, but nothing.

Best plan:

```
Limit  (cost=613080.18..613149.46 rows=100 width=356) (actual time=24934.492..24937.344 rows=100 loops=1)
    ->  Index Scan using "sometable_ts-int" on "sometable"  (cost=0.43..3891408.61 rows=5616736 width=356) (actual time=0.068..24889.459 rows=885000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((jsondata ->> 'ts'::text))::integer >= 1576000473)
Planning time: 0.145 ms
Execution time: 24937.381 ms
```

Can anyone recommend a way to adjust the indexes or queries for these to become faster? Thanks!

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: @jarlh that site is great and all, but reason why I'm asking is because this is JSON and from my attempts, typical indexes techniques didn't work for me.

Comment: @jarlh You mean [this](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), right?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, exactly!

Comment: By the way, `varchar(4096)` is a terrible choice for a primary key columns. Very long values will make the index fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using `OFFSET`](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) like this [will **always** cause bad performance](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

You should use keyset pagination:

Create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON somedb.sometable (id, (jsonData->>'ts'));
```

Then, to paginate, your first query is:

```
SELECT jsonData->'data'
FROM somedb.sometable
WHERE jsonData->>'ts' >= '1576000473'
ORDER BY jsonData->>'ts', id
LIMIT 100;
```

Remember `jsonData->>'ts'` and `id` from the last result row you got in `last_ts` and `last_id`.

Your next page is found with

```
SELECT jsonData->'data'
FROM somedb.sometable
WHERE (jsonData->>'ts', id) > (last_ts, last_id)
ORDER BY jsonData->>'ts', id
LIMIT 100;
```

Keep going like this, and retrieving the 500th page will be as fast as retrieving the first.

Comment: My ids are not monotonically increasing. They are uuids.

Comment: I guess I could create a column.

Comment: That is irrelevant. It only matters that they are unique.

Comment: How does this part work then? `> (last_ts, last_id)`

Comment: Yes, it will. The `id` in that part is just to make sure that there can be no duplicates among the pairs.

Comment: This is promising, but what if there are 200 rows with timestamp 1, we start with `ts >= 0` and get first 100 rows. Last ts we saw was 0. And we will loop forever?

Comment: That's the beauty of the solution and the reason why `id` is included: it will allow to uniquely identify the last row selected on the first page, and the second query will start with the next row. For all rows that have `ts = 0`, the index is sorted by `id`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll play around with it. I'll mark your answer as accepted once I figure out the indexes and get good performance just on the order by ts,id.

Comment: Ok thank you. The idea is that it uses the Row Values syntax/comparison for this solution, which is thankfully fully avaiable in Postgres, but few other databases. Please note whoever reads this solution in the future.